# MongoDB update table without loosing excisting data

Tags: mongodb, csv

i have 2 CSV file , First file contains following data

Set1.csv

```
_id,NAME,AGE,TP
1,AAA,,11111
2,BBB,,99999
3,CCC,,33333
```

Set2.csv

```
_id,NAME,AGE,TP
1,AAA,12,
2,BBB,11,
3,CCC,13,
```

I want to get follwoing Output

```
_id,NAME,AGE,TP
1,AAA,12,11111
2,BBB,11,99999
3,CCC,13,33333
```

Below code i use for get above output but it doent return required output , please help me to sort this.

```
mongoimport -d MyDB -c MyCol --upsert --upsertFields _id --type csv --file  set1.csv  --headerline

mongoimport -d MyDB -c MyCol --upsert --upsertFields _id --type csv --file  set2.csv  --headerline
```

I got following output , null assigned for "TP"

```
_id,NAME,AGE,TP
1,AAA,12,
2,BBB,11,
3,CCC,13,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive above output if you import one .csv file and put data like this

```
_id,NAME,AGE,TP
1,AAA,12,11111
2,BBB,11,99999
3,CCC,13,33333
```

Comment: actually, above data is dummy data , those files contain over 1million datas and used in separate ares (different place)